# Laravel can't find the second passed parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization, nested-routes

I'm passing two parameters to my `ShopController`. one is a `lang` parameter that is in a route group as a prefix for all routes and the second one is a slug passed through a link.
Here's my controller:

```
function show($lang, $slug)
{
    $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    return view('shop_show')->with(['product' => $product]);
}
```

If I pass only one parameter the function takes it as the prefix of the route group, aka the `{lang}` parameter and returns this error:
`Attempt to read property "name" on null`. so I have to pass two.

I die and dumped both `$lang` and `$slug` parameters and they are showing the correct values. `$lang` is `"en"` and `$slug` is `"laptop-1"` or any other slug I pass in. however after going through the function, it returns an error:

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: shopShow] [URI: {lang}/shop/{product}] [Missing parameter: product].
```

This is the route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function () {
    Route::get('/shop/{product}', [ShopController::class, 'show'])->name('shopShow');
});
```

this is the URL of the page:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/shop/laptop-9`

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Here's my `shop_show.blade.php` view file:

```
<x-layout :title="$product->name">
<section class="navbar py-2 border-bottom border-2" style="background-color: #eee; font-weight: 500">
    <div class="container w-75">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a class="text-decoration-none" href="{{ route('landingPage', App::getLocale()) }}">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a class="text-decoration-none" href="{{ route('shopIndex', App::getLocale()) }}">Shop</a>
            </li>

            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a class="text-muted text-decoration-none" href="{{ route('shopShow', ['product' => $product->slug, 'lang' => App::getLocale()]) }}">{{$product->name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="my-5">
    <div class="container w-75 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
        <div class="w-50">
            <div>
                <div>
                   <img id="currentImage" class="active border border-2 rounded-0 p-5 w-75" src='{{ $product->image && file_exists('storage/' . $product->image) ? asset('storage/' . $product->image) : asset('images/not-found.jpg') }}' alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="product-images">
                    <div class="product-thumbnails selected">
                        <img class="w-75" src='{{ $product->image && file_exists('storage/' . $product->image) ? asset('storage/' . $product->image) : asset('images/not-found.jpg') }}' alt="">
                    </div>
                    
                    @if ($product->images)
                        @foreach (json_decode($product->images, true) as $image)
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center product-thumbnails">
                                <img class="w-75" src="{{ file_exists('storage/' . $image) ? asset('storage/' . $image) : asset('images/not-found.jpg') }}" alt="">
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card border-0 w-50">
            <div>
                <h3 class="mb-5">
                    {{$product->name}}
                </h3>

                <span class="text-muted" style="font-weight: 500">
                    {{ $product->details }}
                </span>

                <div class="h3" style="font-weight: 700">
                    ${{$product->price / 100}}
                </div>

                <p class="my-3">
                    {!! $product->description !!}
                </p>

                <form action="{{ route('cartStore', App::getLocale()) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{$product->name}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$product->id}}">
                    <button class="btn py-2 px-3 border border-2 rounded-0 border-secondary" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

@include('partials/might_also_like')

<script>
    const currentImage = document.querySelector('#currentImage');
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.product-thumbnails');

    images.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click', thumbnailClick));

    function thumbnailClick(e) {
        currentImage.classList.remove('active');

        currentImage.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
            currentImage.src = this.querySelector('img').src;
            currentImage.classList.add('active');
        })

        thumbnails.forEach((element) => element.classList.remove('selected'));
        this.classList.add('selected');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you show shop_show blade file code

Comment: it means  $product->slug returned null

Comment: sorry can you elaborate?

Comment: the erorr in blade file .$product->slug passed to route param is returned null

Comment: yes if i pass only one parameter it takes it as `{lang}` parameter which has `"en"` for a value and in that case `$product->slug` is null. but if I pass two parameters it shouldn't mistake the parameters. the first parameter will be `{lang}` and the second one will be the passed product slug. but I get the error that no second parameter has been passed.

Comment: the link comes from another blade file `shop_index`. `shop_show` is the blade file that I'm supposed to get.

Comment: since product is not optional param so you have to pass data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED: There was a link in a component within a component within my layout component (3 times nested) that passed only one param, I fixed it by adding another param.
It's always a better idea to do localization before defining your routes so that you notice an error immediately instead of having to spend hours going through all your view files.